# Best way to turn off SharePoint for clean Point In time backup including the MOSS configuration?

Tags: 2007, backup, configuration, virtual-machine, disaster-recovery

MOSS 2007.  Two Web Front Ends Load balanced with MS. One MOSS Server.  One SSRS Server which is really a Web Front end.  Two SQL Servers Clustered with MS. Content DBs are over a Terabyte so a native MOSS backup is not an option.

The plan is to virtualize all servers but the SQL Database servers.  One time operation where we want to backup our SP databases with MOSS down.

We currently only do SQL backups and are looking to implement DPM, but want to do the virtualization first.

All servers must be up while being virtualized so concerned about  traffic trying to come into SharePoint as well as background processes. We want the SQL DBs to be quite while we back them up.

What's the best way to turn off SharePoint so that we can backup up a quite databases .. especially the MOSS configuration Database.  We don't want to mess too much with the configuration or Central Admin and we don't want to a lot of SharePoint errors going to the logs either.

I thought about just stopping WWW services on the 4 servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the DBs to read only mode and keep your farm up so it's available for users to view info while the backups are occurring, this is a better option than stopping IIS if you have to perform this maintenance during the week.

If it's the weekend where this is occurring, then cutting IIS on the WFEs isn't a horrible option provided it's communicated the environment will be unavailable.